# How was Age of Ultron's post-credit scene even possible?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

At the end of the Avengers: Age of Ultron there is that end credits scene where Thanos picks up the infinity gauntlet and walks off. Where did he get this?

We all know that this will lead to him putting the stones into the gauntlet but the gauntlet is protected in Odin's treasure room is it not? In the first Thor film when the frost giants try to steal that frost cube thingy, only to get incinerated, we can see the infinity gauntlet as a treasure piece in a brief shot. Is there something I missed from any of the other Marvel movies that explain how he came to be in possession of this?

Comment: Relevant question on the SciFi SE: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64885/31029

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per  [cinemablend.com](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Big-Secret-Behind-Infinity-Gauntlet-According-Marvel-Kevin-Feige-71192.html)

> "There are two different gloves. That was not Odin’s vault that you
>   see at the end." - Kevin Feige

That means Thanos doesn't have to grab the Glove from Asgard at all.

Even the gloves are of different hands:

- Left hand glove in *Age of Ultron*

  [image: Thanos seen wearing a left hand glove]
- And right hand in *Thor*

  [image: picture of the right hand glove] [image: glove seen in the vault]

But in *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hela made it clear that it was a fake Gauntlet. And that there is only one real Gauntlet.

Comment: ....DUH!.... ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson sounded dumb to me but now i also got proof.

Comment: Nice! Never thought about that, I will have to read the infinity gauntlet novel soon.

Comment: I strongly suspect the **out-of-universe** explanation is that they didn't have this planned out when they released Thor, so they just put the infinity gauntlet in there as a easter egg.  On the other hand, the comic version *was* a left-hand glove, so it's possible that they could have been leaving themselves an out from all the way back then...

Comment: I specifically wonder, from where did you get those first two screenshots? Your source?

Comment: @Firelord You reminded me to add better images, anyways now i have added images with their source links.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Now first of all, I am not a comics expert and this answer might just be speculation, I do think however that we can't expect much more than that at the current state, seeing how this is a mere post-credit scene for the most recent MCU movie.</sup>

That being said, to my knowledge (which only lacks the 2nd season of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*) there was not really any scene in a previous movie that directly explains how Thanos could get his hands on the gautlet. However, during *Thor: The Dark World* there is a scene where Thor stands in front of Odin and after Thor left it is revealed that Loki, whom we (and *Thor*) believed to have died in Svartalfheim, is actually very much alive and has taken Odin's place as king of Asgard. Now this as well was just a small scene without much elaboration, so we don't actually know what happened thereafter, how long Loki kept playing king or what actually happened to Odin. But it might be very much possible, that Loki is still playing king of Asgard and making evil schemes. Add to this that *Age of Ultron*, particularly Thor's worst fear arc, suggests that there's possibly something awry (or becoming awry) in Asgard. While this was just a fear implanted by Scarlet Witch, there might very well be some truth to it.

And we also know that Loki worked with (or for?) Thanos before, namely in the first *Avengers* movie. So it might be (even if that is really just a big "might") that Loki, disguised as Odin, gave Thanos access to the Infinity Gauntlet.

Comment: I thought that might be possible, but after the events of the first Avengers movie I would have guessed that Loki would want to stay away from Thanos just in case he tries to kill him due to his failure.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, only in less detail. Yes, the only sensible conclusion is that Loki is still in league with Thanos and therefore, wanted to appease his master's wrath. The only other explanation is that Thanos took it by force... which would not have made any sense.

Comment: One thing to note that the infinity gauntlet in Thor had gems in it, nice thing to see how Disney will handle this.

Answer (score 3):

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hela peruses some of the artifacts in the Asgardian treasure vault. When she comes to the supposed Infinity Gauntlet, she flippantly remarks that it's an obvious fake. She also implies that the nearby Tesseract is real (which we already knew, since it was brought to the vault after the events of the Avengers), thus proving that she has the expertise to accurately assess the authenticity of these artifacts.

So the gauntlet in the Asgardian treasure vault is a fake, and the real one is in Thanos' possession.

Comment: I don't think she explicitly said *the gauntlet* was obvious fake. She just said many of the things are fake, while smashing away the gauntlet. However, your answer is still a reasonable deduction from that. It would be  destroyed or floating through the void of space now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We actually get this answered in Infinity War

> Thanos goes to Nidavilir, source of Odin and Thor’s weapons like Mjolnir and such.  Etri the dwarf is who designs and builds these weapons.

After which...

> Thanos, in his typical mode of destruction, gives Etri an ultimatum to face his wrath or build him a weapon capable of wielding all the Infinity Stones.

The post credit scene in Age of Ultron is showing Thanos taking possession of that gauntlet.

> We don’t get to see the action immediately before and after that specific action but is later described by Etri when Thor goes to Nidavilir to create a new Thanos busting weapon.