# What is the current position of all Infinity stones in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

We know that there are six Infinity Stones in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. But as I didn't see the movies in the correct sequence I couldn't understand where the Infinity Stones are right now and who is using them.

So, can anyone please help me by telling me the current status of the Infinity stones?

[image: 'The Infinty Stones' a series of gems in the shape of oval orbs displayed in order with their respective names and colours. In order: 1. The Mind Gem (Red) 2. The Reality Gem (Orange) 3. The Power Gem (Yellow) 4. The Space Gem (Green) 5. The Time Gem (Blue) 6. The Soul Gem (Purple).]

Comment: Either this question should be reworded to refer to movies before Infinity War, or the answer should be updated to reflect the events of Infinity War.

Comment: @EmoryBell no it shouldn't. The date already shows this is an old question. We shouldn't have a precedence to edit questions every time a new movie makes something obsolete. Also the answerer is under no obligation to add new content nor is is appropriate to edit their answer to do so. A new answer would be appropriate if you personally wish that to be added.

Comment: Related: [What is the history of the Tesseract in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, taking into account the events of 'Captain Marvel'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97831/1006)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All information is correct as of *Avengers Endgame (2019)*.

---

All the stones have been obliterated in the main MCU timeline, "reduced to atoms" by Thanos after a second usage of the completed Infinity Gauntlet.  The stones used in the Stark Gauntlet were gathered and then returned to their original timelines at the end of the event now known as "The Blip".

Until there is a significant update in the MCU cannon, it can be implied that the Infinity Stones no longer exist in this timeline and thus, any information below is considered historical or their last known location before being part of the completed Infinity Gauntlet

---

**Mind Gem**

- Last seen In Vision's forehead, giving him life, during the battle of Wakanda.
- Formerly part of Loki's Staff from *The Avengers* (2012).

  [image: Screen capture of The Vision, a character from the movie The Avengers: Age of Ultron. The Vision has the 'Mind Gem' on/within his forehead.]
  [image: Screen Capture of 'Loki's Sceptre' from the movie The Avengers: Age of Ultron, having formerly contained the 'Mind Gem'.]

**Space Gem**

- Last seen with Loki aboard the Grandmaster's ship.
- Formerly in Odin's vault.  Loki passes by it while brining Surtur's crown to the Eternal Flame in *Thor: Ragnarök (2017)*.

  [image: Loki handing the Tesseract presumably to Thanos]

**Time Gem**

- Encased inside the 'Eye of Agamotto', last held by Doctor Strange on Titan.

  [image: Screen capture of the glowing green orb, encased within a bronze coloured elaborately patterned metal casing, known as 'The Eye of Agamotto'.]

**Power Gem**

- On Xandar with the Nova Corps at the end of *The Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 1* (2014).
- Originally encased within the Orb that Star Lord retrieves at the beginning of the film
- It is currently unkown (as of early 2024) how exactly Thanos obtained this stone from Xandar.  The implication is that Xandar was decimated, but hast not been shown.

  [image: Screen capture from the movie The Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 1, showing an elaborate and intricately carved silver coloured orb which opens up and contains the glowing purple 'Power Gem'.]

**Reality Gem**

- Encased within (or in the form of) The Aether
- Last seen in possession of The Collector on Knowhere
- It was given to him by the Warriors Three at the end of *Thor: The Dark World* (2013).

  [image: Screen capture from a scene in the movie Thor: The Dark World, showing 'The Aether', a silvery-black flowing liquid, almost alive, within a red backdrop. Presumably 'The Aether' is or contains the 'Reality Gem'.]

**Soul Gem**

- Last seen on Vormir, held by Thanos
- Only obtainable by permanently sacrificing something the user truly loves (note: this "love" is not required to be reciprocal)

  [image: A picture of Thanos holding the Soul Stone after obtaining it on Vormir]

---

**Bonus side-note**: In the Cinematic Universe there are *two* Infinity Gauntlets - Right and Left.

The Right-Hand Gauntlet was in Loki's possession during Thor: Ragnarok.  However it was shown by Hela to be a faked gauntlet.

[image: Screen capture featuring a 'right-handed' metallic glove or gauntlet, it is golden and has small notches on each main knuckle, as well as a slightly larger on in the top part of the palm, presumably ready to contain the 'Infinity Gems'. The gauntlet looks like it is in a vitrine display.]

The Left-Hand Gauntlet is in Thanos' possession at the end of *The Avengers: Age of Ultron* & throughout *Infinity War*.

[image]

Comment: [Related answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/33905/1190) for you bonus sidenote with word of god.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Show-off :P

Comment: Why are there two gloves if one can (seemingly) hold all 6 stones?

Comment: @HannoverFist In comics there is only one glove, why they made two in films might get explained some day

Comment: Perhaps the first was just an Easter-Egg, then they realised they needed another one for their Thanos story.

Comment: @HannoverFist Because wearing only one glove is ridiculous?

Comment: @HannoverFist one is a fake. It's just a decoration. Odin didn't/couldn't want the real thing in his vault so he had a replica.